# Unable to send PDF file from Supabase Edge Functions

Tags: supabase, deno

```
   serve(async (req) => {. 
     const pdfDoc = await createPdf();  
     return new Response(pdfDoc, {  
        headers: {. 
          ...corsHeaders,  
          "content-type": "application/pdf",  
          "content-length": String(pdfDoc.byteLength),  
     },  
     status: 200,  
  });
```

```
   const { data, error } = await supabase.functions.invoke('create-invoice-pdf', {  
    body: JSON.stringify({email: 'a@gmail.com'}),  
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },  
   })
```

In the above response, data is null and error is
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%', "%PDF-1.7 %"... is not valid JSON
message : "Unexpected token '%', "%PDF-1.7\n%"... is not valid JSON"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%', "%PDF-1.7\n%"... is not valid JSON"

When checked in Network tab, API response has PDF with details like /Size 9
/Root 2 0 R
/Info 3 0 R
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Type /XRef
/Length 42
/W [ 1 2 2 ]
/Index [ 0 9 ]

But the response in JS code received data and error object with the above issue. How to capture that file? Should I use stream to send and receive the data?